# Connecting iPod or MP3 player "breaks" usb

Tags: usb

Occasionally on Lubuntu 12.04 64bit, when I plug in my iPod touch or my Sansa ClipZip+, my USB wifi dongle will stop working, and the device will not be mounted. The only way I can fix this is by restarting it. This doesn't happen every time I plug in one of the two, but it can get very annoying.

What can I do to find out why this is happening? Are there logs I can look at to see why lubuntu's USB stops working? Is there a way to restart usb so I don't have to restart my entire computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To watch the logs as something is connected you can either monitor `kern.log` in `gnome-system-monitor` or other logging software, or use the command-line and enter

```
tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

When your device is connected you will see a lot of information, such as

```
usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
Initializing USB Mass Storage driver...
scsi2 : usb-storage 1-3:1.0
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
USB Mass Storage support registered.
usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     CREATIVE ZEN_Stone
```

You can keep the log open in the terminal and monitor when any errors occur as well. You can grep the log for past errors with `grep -i usb /var/log/kern.log`, but you will probably need to use some more specific search terms with grep such as `error` or the name of your hardware, as just using `usb` as a search term will return a lot of results.

Most of the advice you read to restart the USB subsystem won't work in Ubuntu, and this way here at [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9162799&postcount=1) doesn't seem to work for me, but you could try restarting `udev` by entering

```
sudo service udev restart
```

but you may very well still have to reboot.